# Do I need both a Croatian visa and a Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, croatia, schengen-visas

I am an Indian national and travelling to France and Switzerland for 3 days each, and then to Croatia and Italy for 6 days each. My first destination is France and the last destination is Italy. Since I intend to spend the same time in Croatia and Italy, would I need to apply for a Croatian visa as well?

Answer (score 1):

Croatia allows holders of still-valid Schengen visa with two or multiple entries to enter Croatia without applying for a Croatian visa.

You seem to imagine that this rule only applies if you would still have applied for the visa from a different Schengen country *if Croatia had already been a Schengen member*. But there is no such restriction.

When you apply for a visa for the Schengen part of your trip (from the Italian consulate, since that is your main destination within the area), document the entire trip. You should end up with at least a 2-entry visa with a duration-of-stay of 12 days or more, and that will be enough for you to enter Croatia between the two in-Schengen parts.

Comment: Makhlom : The information on the site is as follows "Please note that in order to apply for a travel visa at the Embassy of Italy, your only destination or your main destination (longest duration of stay) must be Italy. In the absence of a main destination (e.g. same duration of stay in two or more countries) you should apply at the country of first entry because your passport will show the entry stamp of your first destination only." I was wondering , since I will enter Croatia before Italy and I am staying for same duration, would the embassy insist on Croatian Visa?

Comment: @Martian27: Croatia is _not in the Schengen area_, and is therefore not relevant to getting a Schengen visa., You can't **get** a Schengen visa from Croatia, so it would make no sense to say that your application for a Schengen visa should be filed with Croatia instead of with Italy.

Comment: Thanks I understood now. I will share my whole itinerary with the embassy at the time of application.

Comment: @Martian27 the sentence you quote implies, and would be more accurate if it actually said, "your only destination or your main destination (longest duration of stay) *in the Schengen area* must be Italy."  If the sentence were literally true, it would be impossible for anyone to get a Schengen visa for a trip such as yours.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: I got VISA today. I agree with you that the information on the website needs to be modified.